# number at the circumference

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Determine all natural numbers $n$ such that the numbers $1,2,3, . . . ,n$ can be placed on the circumference of a circle, such that for any natural number $s$ with $1 \le s \le \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ there exists an arc having the sum of the whole numbers on it equal to $s$.

We can try with $n =  4$
And it is true for construction 1,3,2,4 ( which in placed at the circumference of the circle at clockwise rotation)
Since we can have $1,2,3,4, 2+3=5, 1+3+2=6 , 2+4+1 =7 , 4+3+1=8 , 3+2+4=9$ and last $ 1+3+2+4=10 $.

From try for some $n$ i have that all positive integer $n$ can be such what the question is so from that i claim that maybe all positive integer $n$ we have it is true but for proff can any one help me????

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, why are you posting unanswered question from the mathlinks combinatorics unsolved problems queue?

Comment: I have tried it for the construction but I cant get the complete proof

Comment: Maybe not only voting the problem but help other solved it is the best way for the one who cant solved it such me

Comment: I'm sorry, I would help if I could. But I can't solve the problem either.

Comment: Your final sentence seems to be different from the question itself.May I know why?

Comment: @rah4927 which sentences do you mean sir?

Comment: @ModdedBear ok may be i will wait another person to answer this problem

Comment: @Deddy,the original question asks us to find all numbers that follow a particular condition.Your final sentence suggests that all natural numbers follow that property.Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Now how to prove this can hold for all postive number $n$ @rah4927

Comment: @Deddy,what I meant was,the question asks us to find the numbers for which a given condition holds.As you have seen yourself,4 satisfies the conditions..But you seem to have already assumed that all numbers satisfy the condition.I was wondering whether this had a specific reason,like empirical evidence or something like that.

Comment: Aaa the configuration i think for $ n $ is such $1,n-1,2,n-2,3,n-3,...$ but the evidence i dont have any idea